# python: simple way to input python data from file

Tags: python, import, persistence

In a shell script one might do something like:

```
myvar='default_value'
source myfile.sh
echo $myvar
```

where myfile.sh is something like:

```
echo "myvar='special_value'" > myfile.sh
```

I know several "safe" ways of doing this in python, but the only way I can think of getting similar behaviour in Python (albeit ugly and unsafe) is the following:

```
myvar = 'default_value'
myimport = 'from %s import *' % 'myfile'
exec(myimport)
print(myvar)
```

where myfile.py is in ./ and looks like:

```
myvar = 'special_value'
```

I guess I would be happiest doing something like:

```
m.myvar = 'default_value'
m.update(__import__(myimport))
```

and have the objects in m updated. I can't think of an easy way of doing this without writing something to loop over the objects.

Comment: What's wrong with just `import myfile` then `myvar = myfile.myvar` or `from myfile import myvar`? You need to explain your use case and why that doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways to look at this question.

> How can I read key-value pairs in python? Is there a standard way to do this?

and

> How can I give full expressive power to a configuration script?

If your question is the first; then the most obvious answer is to use the `ConfigParser` module:

```
from ConfigParser import RawConfigParser
parser = RawConfigParser({"myvar": "default_value"}) # Never use ConfigParser.ConfigParser!
parser.read("my_config")
myvar = parser.get("mysection", "myvar")
```

Which would read a value from a file that looks like a normal INI style config:

```
# You can use comments
[mysection]
myvar = special_value
```

For the second option, when you really want to give full power of python to a configuration (which is rare, but sometimes necessary), You probably don't want to use `import`, instead you should use `execfile`:

```
config = {}
execfile("my_config", config)
myvar = config.get("myvar", "default_value")
```

Which in turn will read from a python script; it will read the global variable `myvar` no matter how the script derives it:

```
import random
myvar = random.choice("special_value", "another_value")
```